# when the page was loaded any times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want when the page was loaded 10 times

```
alert ('hello !!');
```

how to get it ?

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my problem !!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    myfunc = function () {
        if (i++ == 10){
            alert ('hello !!');
        }
    }
    window.onload = myfunc;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for you help :x

Comment: The logic would be:  Check if cookie exists on page load.  If exists, check value and add one.  If not, create and add one.  If value is 10, then show the alert.

Comment: @JusticeErolin I tried to write it,
But each time you load the page the cookie is deleted,Can you write  simple example for your comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [HTML 5 LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html):

```
<html>
    <script>
        var visitCount = localStorage["visitCount"];
        visitCount = parseInt(visitCount);

        if (!visitCount) {
            visitCount = 0;
        }

        visitCount = visitCount + 1;

        if (visitCount >= 10) {
            alert("hello!");
            visitCount = 0;
        }

        localStorage["visitCount"] = visitCount;
    </script>

    <body>
        Hi!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A suggestion: use `if(!visitCount)` instead of `if(visitCount == NaN)`. The code doesn't work for me, but with this change it work. Nice solution. +1

Comment: @John: Javascript is something I use relatively rarely, so I don't know the best practices. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Note that [this table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage) shows the browser support. If your browser doesn't support it, you could fall back to something like [Dojo's implementation](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/1.6/object-store), which implements a fallback to cookies, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with javascript alone.  You need to keep track of how many times the page was opened with a cookie.  Each time the page is loaded, read the cookie, increment the value, check if it is 10. If so, output the message.  If not, write the new value to the cookie.  Alternatively you can do this with server-side code and a session variable.